# PHP: How to decrement a string function by 1?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to access an external API.

When a call a particular API method, it returns a number one higher than I want to display.

However, the API is returning the integer as a string and not an integer.

**Question:** How can I decrement the returned string by 1 since it's not an integer

Essentially, I want to do the follow pseudo-code (that doesn't work):

```
echo external_api() -1; // problem is, this returns "X -1" where "X" is an integer but returned as a strong
```

Comment: Why not just `external_api() - 1` without any casts?? it is php, that is how it works.

Comment: The code as posted should not return "X -1", since there's no concatenation operator to be found anywhere. In fact, it should work the way you want it to work already...

Comment: This doesn't work. This returns "X -1" (literally, where X is an integer)

Comment: `function three() { return "3"; } echo three() - 1;` This outputs `2`. Your problem is somewhere else. Post your real code and/or more of it.

Answer (score 7):

The `external_api()` function echoes the integer (`9`) and returns `NULL`. Thus, when you attempt to subtract from it, you get something like the following:

```
function external_api() {echo "9";}
echo external_api() - 1;
```

...which would produce `9-1`.

Mystery solved.

Now, to fix it. Supposing you can't change the external api...

```
ob_start();
external_api();
$output = ob_get_clean();
echo ((int)$output) - 1;
```

Next time, though, post **everything**, so we're not scratching our heads for an extended period of time.

Comment: +1 Wow, two things to be learned: Never trust the OP (the function did not *return* anything) and (@Jason) if something is *impossible*, look for alternative explanations and test them (just calling `external_api()` without `echo` would have confirmed this).

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the return value as integer :

```
echo ((int) external_api()) - 1;
```

** **EDIT** **

This is the code that I ran

```
function external_api() {
    return "100";
}

echo ((int) external_api()) - 1;
```

and the output is `99`. If this doesn't work for you, then the function is not returning a correct value. Otherwise, please elaborate because it doesn't make any sense.

Moreover, as [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) pointed out, even without casting, PHP is smart enough to do it already on math operators :

```
echo external_api() - 1;
```

will also output `99` so obviously there is something going on in that mysterious function because the problem is not where you say it is.

**BTW** : the result of `"2" -1`; can **never** be `"2 -1"` because `-` is not even a string operator. The only string operator in PHP is `.` for concatenation: `"2" + 1 = 3;` where `"2" . 1 = "21"`

Comment: Doesn't work. If *external_api()* were to = 9, and I want to display 8.  The code above simply displays 9 (and not 8). Weird. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jason I can verify that the code Yanick suggested works. Perhaps your API is returning something other than a number? Perhaps a resource? Can you do a `var_dump()` on the output?

Answer (score 2):

If the function is returning a string, then your code should actually work.  You could try casting the value to an integer though:

```
echo (int)external_api() - 1;
```

**EDIT**

It sounds like you might need to sanitize your data using preg_replace before decrementing it.  Try this:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', external_api()) - 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If *external_api()* were to = 9, and I want to display 8.  The code above simply displays 9 (and not 8). Weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Try running this at your command line (it will return 8): > php -r 'function a() { return "9"; } echo (int)a() - 1;'

Comment: Interestingly enough, for the code `echo "9NULL" - 1;`, PHP will still output 8.

Comment: See my second answer. Figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it with `(int)` or use `intval()` to convert it to an integer first:

```
echo ((int) external_api()) - 1;
```

or

```
echo intval(external_api()) - 1;
```

Casting is generally the fastest.

Comment: Neither work. If *external_api()* were to = 9, and I want to display 8.  The code above simply displays 9 (and not 8). Weird. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try `echo intval(external_api())-1` or if some higher no or other data type floatval too